# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> [Faces Servlet] in filter mapping

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

I am building a control filter for my entityManager in my app, but I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> [Faces Servlet] in filter mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2971)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1169)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
```

when I define `@WebFilter("Faces Servlet")` in my class JPAFilter. I changed to `@WebFilter(".xhtml")`, but the entityManager creates a lot of connections in the db.

My JPAFilter class:

```
@WebFilter("Faces Servlet")
public class JPAFilter implements Filter {

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private String persistence_unit_name = "comex-pu";

    public void destroy() {
        this.entityManagerFactory.close();
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        EntityManager entityManager = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        request.setAttribute("entityManager", entityManager);
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(this.persistence_unit_name);
    }
}
```

My `Faces Servlet` in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is here:

```
@WebFilter("Faces Servlet")
```

You specified `Faces Servlet` as **default `value`** of the annotation (i.e. you did not assign it to any specific attribute name). If you look up the meaning of the default `value` in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html) of `@WebFilter`, then you read this:

> `value`
>   The URL patterns to which the filter applies

So, the default value of the annotation is interpreted as an URL pattern. This totally explains the exception you got:

```
Invalid <url-pattern> [Faces Servlet] in filter mapping
```

You're basically trying to specify the servlet name `Faces Servlet` as an URL pattern. You need to specify the servlet name via `servletNames` attribute instead.

```
@WebFilter(servletNames = { "Faces Servlet" })
```

That should solve the exception.

---

However, this won't necessarily solve your [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info) of "too many connections", because this change will let your filter still behave exactly the same as when you configured it as `@WebFilter("*.xhtml")`. This is because the servlet name `"Faces Servlet"` is according to `web.xml` mapped to .... yes, also `*.xhtml`. So the net effect is that there is no difference whatsoever.

Most probably you actually wanted to skip JSF resources in your filter (CSS/JS/image assets). They namely also match the `*.xhtml` URL pattern. You need to solve this differently. Just let your filter skip URLs starting with context path plus `ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER`. Put this code in the very beginning of your `doFilter()` method.

```
if (request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}
```